# Cannot set property statusCode of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

I'm trying to create a backend to my application and i'm actually writing the route login for the users but I encounter a error when I test the route with Postman, this error is :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'statusCode' of undefined

at the line

> this.response.statusCode = 401

Here my code :

```
import Rider from '../../models/riders'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export default class LoginService {
/**
 * @param {String} email
 * @param {String} password 
 * */
constructor(email, password) {
    this.email = email
    this.password = password

    this.reponse = {
        statusCode: 200,
        responseData: {},
    }
}

loginRider() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.checkIdentifiant()
          .then((r) => {
            // identifiant correct, l'user peut se connecter
            console.log(r)
            console.log("apres then apres checkidentifiant")
            this.response.responseData = {
              token: jwt.sign(r.toJSON(), process.env.TOKEN_PASSWORD),
            }
            resolve(this.response)
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log("dans le catch login rider")
            console.log(e)
            // erreur lors de l'authentification / error code unauthorized 401
            this.response.statusCode = 401
            this.response.responseData = {
              error: 'unauthorized',
              error_description: 'Identifiants incorrect',
            }

            // On log l'erreur dans la console pour l'admin
            resolve(this.response)
          })
      })
}

/**
* Vérifie le mot de passe et l'email de l'user qui tente de se connecter
*
* @returns {boolean}
*/
checkIdentifiant() {
// on cherche un livreur ayant le même mail que celui fourni dans la BDD
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Rider.findOne({ email: this.email, password: this.password }, (err, rider) => {
    if (err || !rider) {
      console.log("identifiant invalide dans le checkidentifiant")
      reject()
    }
    // si le rider est trouvé dans la BDD
    if (rider) {
      console.log("identifiant correct, dans le check identifiant")
      // pas sécurisé, à améliorer
      resolve(rider)
    }
  })
})
}
}
```

The console.log I put show me that I run in the block catch of LoginRider.

I use nodeJS and expressJS to write my backend and my database use MongoDB. Postman is used for testing the API

Comment: `this.response` seems to be undefined. Where is your route defined? There should be references to `(req, res)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a typo in the first declaration of this.response

```
  this.reponse   => this.response
```

Comment: Thank you, that was just that... sorry for this.

Comment: @Pixelyoda , you can accept my answer if it was just that

Comment: Yes thank you but now that weird, the findOne method inside checkIdentifiant return a null object for rider but I already  have my database running in local environnement and the schema Rider and the data exist...